# not able to convert from 'UnityEngine.Touch' to 'float' in line 18

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not able to convert from 'UnityEngine.Touch' to 'float' in line no.18  Please help?

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v) * movementSpeed;

public class RacketPlayer1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public float movementSpeed;

    private void FixedUpdate(){

        if(Input.touchCount>0)
        {
            UnityEngine.Touch v = Input.touches[0];

            if(v.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || v.phase == TouchPhase.Moved )
            {           
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v) * movementSpeed;
            }   
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is Line 18 in this code?

Comment: The constructor for `Vector2` requires a pair of `float`. You have passed it one `int` which can be implicitly converted to a `float`, and one `Touch` which can't. Which property of your `Touch` do you want to use to create the `Vector2`?

Answer (score 2):

Because vector2 => (float x,float y) , I guess you want to set position so

```
 GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v) * movementSpeed;
```

change to :

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v.position.y) * movementSpeed;
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html